# How to get the current user post and it's ID?

Tags: posts, get-posts

I have a site setup so users can publish a post via the frontend, what happens is, there post is posted as a status, 'Pending Review, in a custom post type.

How can i get the post ID for this particular post the user has just published?

The posts author status is also set to the particular user that submitted the post.

I can get the author's ID using this.

```
$user_ID = get_current_user_id();
```

Hope this makes sense and thanks for the help.

Comment: Are you not using `wp_insert_post` function to create post? This function returns the ID of created post.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, no i'm using the gravityforms plugin where the users can publish posts via the frontend. Basically some code that finds the post from the authous ID and gets the posts ID is what i'm researching for.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So digging around a little i couldn't find a solution where the **WP_Query** wasn't used, so i just stuck with the query method, Using WP_Query this snippet will display the latest post that is published by the user that is logged in.

```
$user_id = get_current_user_id();

$args=array(
    'post_type' => 'POSTTYPE',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'author' => $user_id
);                       

$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
    the_title();
endwhile;
```

Hope this helps someone.

Cheers

Matt

Comment: "post_status" = published you mentioned wrong. It's actually misguiding users.